# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" for custom dirctive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` for customer directive of auto-complete. In chrome browser's console  it is giving
`VM80623:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. When I click on `VM80623:1`, it gives `void();` in File name **VM80623**

I implement the following directive from following link, there is same error: type any character, auto-complete search box and select, you will get the same error..

Link: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/ajax-based-autocomplete-typeahead-directive-in-angularjs/

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.directive('Autocomplete', ['Authentication', '$http', function(AuthenticationService, $http){
        return {
            restrict : 'AEC',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
              modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directives/autocomplete/autocomplete.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
              scope.searchCustomer = function(customerSearch){
                  var params = {
                    'session_key': Authentication.GetSessionKey(),
                    'q': customerSearch
                  };
                  if (!customerSearch){
                    return;
                  }
                  var url = config.url+'/api/search';
                  return $http.post(url, params).then(function(response){
                        var data = response.data;
                        if(data.error == 0) {
                          scope.TypeAheadData = data.result;
                          return data.result;
                        }
                      });
              }
              scope.handleSelection = function(item){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
                scope.modeldisplay = item;
                scope.selected = true;
              };
              scope.isCurrent = function(index) {
                return scope.current == index;
              };
              scope.setCurrent = function(index) {
                scope.current = index;
              };
            }
          };
      }]);
  })();
```

Comment: Fourth line from the bottom there is trailing comma that is going to cause an issue

Comment: Use a  syntax linter, either in your IDE or even an online one to find syntax problems. This should not have become a question on this site when tools exist to find problem

Comment: @charlietfl, I this not due to syntax problem, have look in http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/ajax-based-autocomplete-typeahead-directive-in-angularjs/,  type any character and select, you will get the same error, what I am getting....

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted your code into IntelliJ; and the problem appears to be this line:

```
var url = config.url'/api/search';
```

You'll need to do something to concatenate the variable and the string, probably like this:

```
var url = config.url + '/api/search';
```

There are a handful of other minor syntax errors; but nothing I'd expect to prevent the code from running.

In this snippet:

```
scope: {
  modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay',
},
```

The comma is not needed:

```
scope: {
  modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay'
},
```

Add a semicolon at the end of the searchCustomer method:

```
scope.searchCustomer = function(customerSearch){
  // other code here
};
```

And a comma is not needed at the end of the link function:

```
            } // remove comma here,
        };
    }]);
})();
```

And finally, IntelliJ also flagged the else return in the $http.post result function:

```
                    return $http.post(url, params).then(function(response){
                        var data = response.data;
                        if(data.error == 0) {
                            scope.TypeAheadData = data.result;
                            return data.result;
                        }
/* not needed because we are at end of method 
                       else {
                            return;
                        } */
                    });
```

Here is the full updated code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.directive('Autocomplete', ['Authentication', '$http', function(AuthenticationService, $http){
        return {
            restrict : 'AEC',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directives/autocomplete/autocomplete.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
                scope.searchCustomer = function(customerSearch){
                    var params = {
                        'session_key': Authentication.GetSessionKey(),
                        'q': customerSearch
                    };
                    if (!customerSearch){
                        return;
                    }
                    var url = config.url + '/api/search';
                    return $http.post(url, params).then(function(response){
                        var data = response.data;
                        if(data.error == 0) {
                            scope.TypeAheadData = data.result;
                            return data.result;
                        }
/*                        else {
                            return;
                        } */
                    });
                };
                scope.handleSelection = function(item){
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
                    scope.modeldisplay = item;
                    scope.selected = true;
                };
                scope.isCurrent = function(index) {
                    return scope.current == index;
                };
                scope.setCurrent = function(index) {
                    scope.current = index;
                };
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: @geeks You haven't provided enough to code for this to be a testable runnable app.  You may consider doing so; perhaps in the form of a plunker.

Comment: I have this implementation from http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/ajax-based-autocomplete-typeahead-directive-in-angularjs/  There same error is comming

Comment: @geeks Please put together a plunker or something similar so it is easy to review and edit the code to try to diagnose what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Issues was with the following lines:

1. scope: {
             modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay',   // this extra , need to be removed
           }
2. var url = config.url'/api/search'  // config.url & '/api/search' need to be concatinated

Correct code is attached below:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.directive('Autocomplete', ['Authentication', '$http', function(AuthenticationService, $http){
        return {
            restrict : 'AEC',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
              modeldisplay:'= modeldisplay'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directives/autocomplete/autocomplete.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
              scope.searchCustomer = function(customerSearch){
                  var params = {
                    'session_key': Authentication.GetSessionKey(),
                    'q': customerSearch
                  };
                  if (!customerSearch){
                    return;
                  }
                  var url = config.url + '/api/search';
                  return $http.post(url, params).then(function(response){
                        var data = response.data;
                        if(data.error == 0) {
                          scope.TypeAheadData = data.result;
                          return data.result;
                        }
                        else {
                          return;
                        }
                      });
              }
              scope.handleSelection = function(item){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(item);
                scope.modeldisplay = item;
                scope.selected = true;
              };
              scope.isCurrent = function(index) {
                return scope.current == index;
              };
              scope.setCurrent = function(index) {
                scope.current = index;
              };
            },
          };
      }]);
  })();
```